# When decoding an object from NSCoder, what's the best way to abort?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, serialization, nscoding

I'm decoding a custom object from a cached serialization.  I've versioned++ the object since it was encoded, and if the serialized version is an old version I want to just throw it away.  I was under the impression that I could just return nil from my initWithCoder: method and all would be well.  That's throwing an error though.

**EDIT** - Per NSObject's +version: documentation "The version number applies to NSArchiver/NSUnarchiver, but not to NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver. A keyed archiver does not encode class version numbers.".  I'm using a keyed archiver so that approach won't help.

<strike>I am using my own embedded version number, not the NSObject version + NSCoder's versionForClassName:.  Is that the way to go about this?  Will NSCoder automatically abort attempting to decode if the Class versions don't match, or do I need to do this check manually.</strike>

I'm currently doing this:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (![coder containsValueForKey:@"Class.User.version"]) {
        // Version information missing
        self = nil;
        return nil;
    }

    NSInteger modelVersion = [coder decodeIntForKey:@"Class.User.version"];
    if (modelVersion < USER_MODEL_VERSION) {
        // Old user model, discard
        self = nil;
        return nil;
    }

    ...
}
```

and I'm getting this error when it tries to decode old versions

```
-[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:]: number of objects (0) not equal to number of keys (46)'
```

This all seems odd because initializers can fail for any number of reasons, and the pattern is to return nil in that case, so should this really crash a decoder?

**EDIT** - Per [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/compatibility.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001055-BCICFFGE) it sounds like I'm approaching this the right way.  There does not appear to be, however, a mechanism for completely aborting decoding if an object is old and out of date.  I don't have or want an upgrade path from the old object, so what do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of setting `self` to `nil`, set all of the individual properties that you decode to `nil`, then return `self`. So, write this:

```
if (modelVersion < USER_MODEL_VERSION) {
    // Old user model, discard
    object1 = nil;
    object2 = nil;
    ...
    object46 = nil;
}
return self;
```

This will essentially return an object of the right type and all, but all properties will be `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, that's something that could be done but it ends up requiring me to do a two-pass decode.  Once to decode and again to remove any objects with nil or a special flag set.  The bigger issue I see is that it's perfectly legitimate for an init method to return nil, and they may do so for a variety of reasons aside from this one.  The fact that returning nil from an init crashes a decoder seems like a bug to me.  Anyway, sounds like it probably is a bug, so I'll accept this as a functional workaround in the meantime.

Comment: You are interpreting Apple's documentation as "Don't decode old, obsolete values". What it actually means is "Don't _encode_ old, obsolete values, then you don't have to decode them". So decode them once, then don't write them at the end.